# Rotated elements overlap each other

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to fix this, when I rotate 2 elements, they overlap each other because the width and height don't swap.

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/aez4uc3u/

```css
a {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
  <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: One below the other

Comment: @MichaelMorin, by below you mean the 2nd is to the right of the 1st?

Answer (score 2):

Rotate the container and display the childs as `inline-block` seems to do the trick.

```css
.container {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.container a {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
    <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the parent.

```css
a {
  display: block
}

div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">This is the first link</a>
  <a href="#">This is the second link</a>
</div>
```

Positioning the div as you might like will take additional transforms and, perhaps, adjusting the `transform-origin` property.

You shoud also be aware that `transform` is **purely** visual. It does **not** actually affect the positioning or margins of elements.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could do `inline-block` on the div and use a different `transform-origin` to put it in the top left corner. I was only able to place it either far left or far top, but not both.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm trying to do. Let's add a context here, I have a 50px sidebar on my website that contains <a> tags with a -90deg angle. The problem is that after I rotate my <a> tags, they both overlap each others and they are very difficult to position without absolute.

Comment: @MichaelMorin it would be helpful if you added a visual to your question so it's clear what the objective is.